# Why are polymorphic associations not supported by inverse_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

From [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations):

> There are a few limitations to inverse_of support:
>
> - They do not work with :through associations.
> - They do not work with polymorphic associations.
> - They do not work with :as associations.
> - For belongs_to associations, has_many inverse associations are ignored.

Comment: [this is how](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L513-L514) they designed it and [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L549)

Comment: The above comment should tell you why it doesn't work. Code explains better than any humans. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer true. The `inverse_of` is supported by through, polymorphic and `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations. The automatic detection however is not supported for `through` and associations which define `foreign_key`.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations